# Simple Rails 3 blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, blogs

I have an app that I would like to add a blog to. I'd like to integrate it with my current site.  I only have a few simple requirements:

- Being able to add formatting (headers, paragraphs, etc..)
- Adding images that can be embedded in the content.
- Categories

That's it! I don't want to start from scratch, so a simple gem would be ideal. I don't want a big full featured blog because it will undoubtebly contain many things I don't need. Is there a gem that will allow me to add this functionality to my site easily, or should I just go ahead and build it myself? If so, do you have any resources that could help me with my first 2 requirements (I don't know how exactly I could make paperclip work with the second one)

I'll be hosting this site on Heroku.

Thanks!

Comment: you first bullet list functionality is not so clear can you please ellaborate?

Comment: @sannankhalid Think of a simple version of wordpress.  I'd like to be able to include tags in the content and have them work. for example, save the content of a page as "<h2>Title</h2><p>content</p>" and have it display using the html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Enkiblog](https://github.com/xaviershay/enki). It's small and simple, so you can easy customize it.

And i host it on Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this rails app on github:
https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue

Was looking for the same solution. Adding a blog on an existing site on rails. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Some rudimentary Googling brought back Typo and Jekyll. They are non-simplistic but you can strip and chuck what you won't need, surely.

- https://github.com/fdv/typo
- https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with with [nesta](http://nestacms.com/)