# want to add a blog in existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i am working on an accounting project in rails3 and it has some features of payroll as well. Now i want to start a blog in my existing project. Blogs flow is something like this "In blog posts can be created by only super admin and read by everyone. Here super admin is the owner/ creator of the project.I have many companies registered and super admin dose not
belong to any company.
"

One solution is that i can manage separate database for blog so that super admin log in separately and create posts.

Comment: What's the question anyway? ;-)

Comment: how to add a blog feature in existing rails3 application without affecting other features.

Comment: What are you looking for? code? tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following questions & answers useful
[A clean minimal gem to add a simple blog to existing app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276145/a-clean-minimal-gem-to-add-a-simple-blog-to-existing-app)
[Simple Rails 3 blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427412/simple-rails-3-blog)